# Can Battlefield 3 run on the current version of Ubuntu?

Tags: games

I am currently building a gaming PC of my own and was wanting to cut out the ridiculous cost of $100 for windows 7 or 8 for my budget build. Is there any way that battlefield 3 could be ran with moderate to high settings with a high consistency on the current version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is no. Ubuntu cannot run windows games that use 3D extensively unless there is a specific version for Linux. Wine doesn't cut it as most games will not work if they use 3D extensivley. Some 3D games work, but they tend to be 5-10 year old games,

I forked out for the extra money for Windows and use it for Games only. A linux only gaming rig will limit the games you play. The only game I play on Linux is Minecraft but that is a cross platform game. All my first person shooters are on Windows.

Comment: I don't think the split between old and new games is necessarily valid. Some recent, graphically heavy games work perfectly with equivalent frame rates under Wine and windows. I cannot speak for the game in question, but it is true that relying entirely on Wine to play games can be frustrating. There is always a risk with online games where updates are required that they may work today but be broken in future.

Comment: @chronitis Agreed, and my time is worth more than the cost of Windows so I run both to avoid those issues.

Answer (score 1):

Update on Linux gaming:

The best way to play games on Linux these days is with [Lutris](https://lutris.net/).

For anyone still wishing to play BF3 on Ubuntu, you can follow this guide below:
https://lutris.net/games/battlefield-3/

Also make sure that your hardware meets the recommended requirements for this game. (Ideally you want a more powerful PC to compensate for any lagging).

Answer (score 0):

You can play Battlefield: Bad Company 2 using winetricks, but I don't think Battlefield 3 will work. At least until they make a new update.